# How to Hide rest of the region when user clicks pie chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have **pie chart** representation of user locations as below in **figure 1**,i have successfully made the representation working but how can i make the rest of users **hidden as figure 2** when click any particular sector ?

**Figure 1**:

[image]

Figure 2:

[image]

Javascript :

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'users location'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Africa',   45.0],
                ['Asia',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Australia',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Europe',    8.5],
                ['North America',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/5oLmj00L/)

Comment: This fiddle was the best I could do for you: http://jsfiddle.net/5oLmj00L/1/. It creates an undesired behaviour of making the selected slice's value to be 100% so I won't post it as an answer, but hopefully it helps other people (or even yourself) to reach a more definitive solution from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **`plotOptions.series.point.events.click`** function to tell the chart exactly what to do after the click of a slice:

```
series: {
    point: {
        events: {
            click: function () {
                var index = this.x;
                $('.highcharts-series-group g path').toggle();
                $('.highcharts-series-group g path:nth-child(' + (index+1) + ')').toggle();

                $('.highcharts-data-labels path').toggle();
                $('.highcharts-data-labels path:nth-child(' + (index+1) + ')').toggle();

                $('.highcharts-data-labels g').toggle();
                $($('.highcharts-data-labels g').get(index)).toggle();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first two toggles are for the slices themselves. **`$('.highcharts-series-group g path')`** refers to all the colored slices in the chart, and I changed back the one user just clicked by adding **`:nth-child`**.

The second pair of toggles are for the lines coming out of the slices connecting the **datalabels** to them. And the third pair is for the **datalabels**.

Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5oLmj00L/3/).

Answer (score 2):

And example in pure Highcharts. As an another answer, use `pie.point.events.click` handler, to hide/show elements: http://jsfiddle.net/5oLmj00L/8/

```
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        var _self = this,
                            undef,
                            method = _self.clicked ? "show" : "hide";

                        Highcharts.each(this.series.data, function(p, i) {
                            if(p !== _self) {
                                // hide/show slice
                                if(p.graphic) {
                                    p.graphic[method]();
                                }
                                // hide/show label
                                if(p.dataLabel) {
                                     p.dataLabel[method]();   
                                }
                                // hide/show connector
                                if(p.connector) {
                                     p.connector[method]();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        // set flag for next click:
                        _self.clicked = _self.clicked !== undef ? !_self.clicked : true;
                    }    
                }
            }
```